# videoタグにmargin使用できますか？

Tags: html, css

videoタグにmargin使用できますか？
HTML Living Standard は、HTML の仕様なので(？)、CSS使用可能と思ったのですが…

Comment: 試してみればわかることだと思いますが、なぜ疑問に思ったのでしょうか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

可能です。

> #### 8.3 Margin properties: 'margin-top', 'margin-right', 'margin-bottom', 'margin-left', and 'margin'<sup>[[1]](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties)</sup>
>
> `'margin'`
>
> - Value:      `<margin-width>{1,4}` | `inherit`
> - Initial:      see individual properties
> - Applies to:   all elements except elements with table display types other than `table-caption`, `table` and `inline-table`
> - Inherited:    no
> - Percentages:      refer to width of containing block
> - Media:    visual
> - Computed value:   see individual properties

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #ffa;
}

video {
  display: block;
  margin: 35px auto 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #faf;
}
```

```html
<!-- 動画元: https://wedistill.io/videos/state-fair-2013-hd -->
<video width="400" autoplay controls>
  <source src="https://wedistill.io/uploads/videos/processed/34/State-Fair-2013-HD.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```